# Roblox - How would I make a script that closes an open GUI when another is opened?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, roblox

I have two GUI's that are opened by a button each at the top of the screen, but I want to make it so that if someone tries to open the second GUI with the first open, it will close the first one before opening the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```lua
local frames = {
    [buttonA] = frameA;
    [buttonB] = frameB;
}
for button,frame in pairs(frames) do
    button.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
        if frame.Visible then
            -- If we try to reopen the current frame, close it
            frame.Visible = false
            return
        end
        -- Close all frames and make ours visible
        for k,v in pairs(frames) do
            -- 'v == frame' is true if it's our frame
            v.Visible = v == frame
        end
    end)
end
```

You should also check out the [ROBLOX Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com). It has some nice tutorials for Lua and stuff like opening/closing GUIs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really know how i'd make this work. If it helps, the names of the screenGUI's are GameUpdateLog, Instructions, and GamepassShop. The frames inside that are UpdateLog, ShopInterface, and InsInterface. The buttons are also called OpenLog, OpenInstructions, and OpenShop.

Comment: Why don't you put everything in one screengui? Then you just do ```[gui.OpenLog] = gui.UpdateLog, [gui.OpenInstructions] = gui.InsInterface, etc```

Answer (score 0):

100% WORKS
To make an opening and closing gui...Put this script:
 FIRSTGUINAME is your first gui, rename it and SECONDGUINAME is your second gui name so...

FIRSTGUINAME = script.Parent -- very important classifying info
SECONDGUINAME = script.Parent.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild(YOUR SECOND GUI)

FIRSTGUINAME.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    SECONDGUINAME.Visible = not Visible

Thats all, now just copy paste this and your set

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close a GUI if another one is open you can try this code:

```
GUI1 = (insert)
GUI2 = (insert)

GUI.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
if GUI1.Visible == false then
if GUI2.Visible == true then
GUI2.Visible = false
GUI1.Visible = true
else
GUI.Visible = true
end
else 
GUI1.Visible = false
end
```

If you are into the fancy stuff with the tweens, you might have to do that research yourself.